# SQL query where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have this line in my sql query:

```
WHERE client = $id
    AND (isinvoiced = 0) OR (isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1)
```

which gets more results than I am expecting.  However, if I write it like this:

```
WHERE client = $id
    AND (isinvoiced = 0) OR (isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1 and client = $id)
```

then it gets me the results I wanted, but this is the best way to write this? I just don't want run into any more issues with this code.

Comment: Google for [Distributivity rewrite rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity).

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between `a AND b OR c` and `a AND (b OR c)`?  Your example is more clearly written as `(a AND b) OR c`, not what you really want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need one more set of `()` around the entire `AND` clause.  This states that `client = $id` MUST be true, and either of the other conditions must also me true = `isinvoiced = 0` OR the combination of `isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1`.

```
 WHERE client = $id
    AND ((isinvoiced = 0) OR (isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1))
```

Comment: Perfect Michael, thats exactly what I am looking for, thanks again...I will vote for your answer when it lets me.

Comment: If `isinvoiced = 1` is exactly the opposite case of `isinvoiced = 0` (i.e. `isinvoiced` can hold no other value, nor `NULL`), you can simplify it even further: `WHERE client = $id AND (isinvoiced = 0 OR isrecurring = 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a parenthesis around your `AND` clause:

```
WHERE client = $id
    AND ((isinvoiced = 0) OR (isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where client = $id
    and (
        isinvoiced = 0
        or (
            isinvoiced = 1
            and isrecurring = 1
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

```
WHERE client = $id AND ((isinvoiced = 0) OR (isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1))
```

If you don't put the extra blaquets it will make an `OR` with the client restiction and gives more results.

Answer (score 0):

As regards SQL, you should aim to write search conditions in [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) ("a seires of `AND` clauses"). There are various [rewrite rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) to assist in this.

The [distributive rewrite law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) is useful in this case i.e.

```
( P AND Q ) OR R   <=>   ( P OR R ) AND ( Q OR R )
```

In your case:

```
( isinvoiced = 0 ) OR ( isinvoiced = 1 AND isrecurring = 1 )
```

may be rewritten as:

```
( isinvoiced = 0 OR isinvoiced = 1 ) AND ( isinvoiced = 0 OR isrecurring = 1 )
```

Therefore, the whole search condition without unwieldy parens:

```
....
WHERE client = $id
      AND ( isinvoiced = 0 OR isinvoiced = 1 ) 
      AND ( isinvoiced = 0 OR isrecurring = 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the initial where clause

```
remove -> WHERE client = $id
```

and just have

```
 WHERE (isinvoiced = 0) OR (isinvoiced = 1 and isrecurring = 1 and client = $id)
```

Does that get you the results you want?

Comment: The OP wants to match on `client` all the time. See the accepted answer.