# How to add where condition to sql with JSqlParser?

Tags: java, sql, jsqlparser

I want to add where condition to sql with JSqlParser, for example:

Before:

```
select * from test_table where a=1 group by c
```

After:

```
select * from test_table where a=1 and b=2 group by c
```

However, I cannot find any example codes.

Comment: Welcome, @Zhang Junlong! Do the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283464/sql-query-where-clause) help you at all?

Comment: @MartinJ.H. Thanks, but it doesn't help. I want to manipulate sql query with a Java library -- JSqlParser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be:

```
String sql = "select * from test_table where a=1 group by c";
Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
Expression where = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression("a=1 and b=2");
((PlainSelect) select.getSelectBody()).setWhere(where);
System.out.println(select.toString());
```

First, you have to parse the existing SQL. Using this **PlainSelect** cast you are getting access to the **where** clause of your statement, at least at the object it holds it.

The **where** expression is generated using the convenience method `CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression`.

The output of those statements is:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 GROUP BY c
```

Comment: Is there a way to add condition to sql without override?

Comment: Override? You can just replace the where statement. Take the expression it has and add what you want.

Comment: You overriding  a=1 condition with a=1 and b=2. The question is I want to add new condition to current conditition. Expression hasn't got add function to add new conditions when you get where expression from PlainSelect.  [My Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510210/how-to-add-new-condition-with-jsqlparser/62528386#62528386)

Comment: Create an AndExpression, set left to actual and right to the new condition and then set this using setWhere.