# How to add new condition with JSqlParser?

Tags: java, jsqlparser

I want to add new condition to my sql. For example If query is;

```
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

I can add new where cause with this codes;

```
@Override
protected void setLimit(final PlainSelect ps,final long rowLimit) {
    Expression where = ps.getWhere();
    if(where == null) {
         try {
            where = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression("ROWNUM < " + (rowLimit+1) );
        } catch (JSQLParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ps.setWhere(where);
}
```

This codes changes the query to

```
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE ROWNUM < 10;
```

...

But the problem is when query is like;

```
 SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID = 10 AND EMP_ID = 10 AND FIRST_NAME = 'Steven';
```

I cannot add new condition to current condition. Is there a way to change this query to like;

```
 SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID = 10 AND EMP_ID = 10 AND FIRST_NAME = 'Steven' AND ROWNUM < 10;
```

Is there a way to do that with JSqlParser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here are two possible solutions for this (this time a bit more than my previous comment :) ):

```
    var sql = "SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID = 10 AND EMP_ID = 10 AND FIRST_NAME = 'Steven'";
    var select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
    var plainselect = (PlainSelect) select.getSelectBody();
    
    //1. add another condition by deparsing the old one and integrate it into
    //a new expression, which is parsed and then set into your statement.        
    var where = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression(plainselect.getWhere() 
           + " and ROWNUM < 10");
   
    //2. second is building a new AndExpression and sets the left item to the
    //original where condition and adds a new condition as the right item.
    var where2 = new AndExpression(plainselect.getWhere(),
           CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression("ROWNUM < 10"));
    
    //output both versions. in fact they should and are identical.
    plainselect.setWhere(where);
    System.out.println(select.toString());
    
    plainselect.setWhere(where2);
    System.out.println(select.toString());
```

This code outputs the following twice:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID = 10 AND EMP_ID = 10 AND FIRST_NAME = 'Steven' AND ROWNUM < 10
```

This is a Java >=V10 code. However with slight adjustments it runs using JDK 8 as well.

1. This variant just transforms the actual where statement into a string and then build with it what condition you want. This resulting string expression is then parsed using JSqlParser (**CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression**) and this resulting expression is set into the parsed plain select statement (**plainselect.setWhere**)
2. The second variant uses the parsed objects and build an **AndExpression** around it. The expression to add is constructed as well or parsed using **CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression** again and added to the constructed **AndExpression** as well.

It is important to know, that this constructs some kind of **JSqlParser** object tree items and does not map one to one to the actual semantics of your SQL. For this you should parenthesis to ensure this, again using type 1 or 2. By the way parenthesis are constructed using the **Parenthesis** object.

So using this technique you can do all kinds of changes to **JSqlParsers** object tree.