# Hierarchy Query in SQL Server - Get hierarchy of particular manager details

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

If I select Manager Id =1 corresponding all employees 1,2,3 and 4 in the same format should get filtered. Like wise, if I select manger ID = 6, Employees 5 and 6 should get returned in the output.

Input data:

[image: Input data]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283464/sql-query-where-clause)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299484/good-examples-of-database-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question and edit your question.

Comment: 1. Please do your research before asking. Basically, the answer to questions like this is always a recursive cte. 2. Please avoid posting images instead of sample data. Instead, read the instructions on the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and follow the recipe there.